# Marker title on google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

**Current Scenario**
I need a solution regarding google map ,Currently i am able to open google maps via both url and sdk i want to populate title on the marker of google map while i open it via browser .

```
NSString *url = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%@+%@+%@",road_Str,pin_Str,city_Str];
    NSLog(@"str%@",url);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D rdOfficeLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[latArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue], [[lngArr objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]);
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?q=%@,%@,%@&center=%f,%f",road_Str,city_Str,pin_Str,rdOfficeLocation.latitude,rdOfficeLocation.longitude];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

Answer (score 1):

The marker is created at coordinates (10,20) and displays the string "Hello world" in an info window when clicked.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 20);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"Hello World";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj ,But i need to do it on browser url i mean on google api.

Comment: In your code marker will plot on given mapView_  not on browser map

Comment: oh...now i got your point exactly... read here...you got it:          https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro